# Yahoo UI Compressor error The attribute "Include" in element <CssFiles> is unrecognized

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, css, minify

I'm implementing CSS and JS minification and combining using Yahoo UI Compressor.  I'm following this article:

http://helios.ca/2011/07/12/asp-net-mvc-merge-minify-javascript-on-the-fly/

but I get an error when building:

error MSB4066: The attribute "Include" in element  is unrecognized.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107757/using-msbuild-with-vs2010-generated-vcxproj-file-as-target-error-msb4066-at probably is related to .NET version of MSBuild

Comment: I don't really know the version of my MSBuild, nor how to find out.

Comment: You can use '/version' to get details... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx

Comment: I went to the Visual Studio Command Prompt on my local server and typed MSBuild /version and got 4.0.30319.1.  Not sure what version is on the build server.

Comment: Your solution's target is .NET 4 one or a previous version?