# MSBuild says 'Label' attribute unrecognized only when I import a particular targets file

Tags: msbuild

When I use the following imports together:

```
<Import Project="$(SlowCheetahTargets)" Condition="Exists('$(SlowCheetahTargets)')" Label="SlowCheetah" />
<Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\packages\SpecFlow.1.9.0\tools\TechTalk.SpecFlow.targets" Condition="Exists('$(SolutionDir)\packages\SpecFlow.1.9.0')" />
```

I get this build error:

> The attribute "Label" in element <Import> is unrecognized

I can remove the Label attribute from the first Import element or completely remove the second import element to get rid of the error.

Can someone explain what is going on? It seems like the contents of the second targets file is changing the version of MSBuild being used...somehow.

*Note: You can get these targets by adding SlowCheetah and Specflow NuGet packages to your project.*

Comment: see the answer here :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107757

Comment: possible duplicate of [using MSBuild with VS2010-generated vcxproj file as target -- error MSB4066 ("attribute Label in element is unrecognized")](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107757/using-msbuild-with-vs2010-generated-vcxproj-file-as-target-error-msb4066-at)

Comment: @AlexeyShcherbak, that answer doesn't apply because the label attribute is valid until I add another Import. Is Visual Studio changing MSBuild versions on me?

Comment: @stijn, that answer doesn't apply because the label attribute is valid until I add another Import. Is Visual Studio changing MSBuild versions on me?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. I just pasted the code shown in some project files at different locations and it never complains. So please add more info: VS version, where in the project file are these imports, ...

Comment: @stijn Do you have the specified .targets available to your project? The import statements do nothing without them.

Comment: No I don't have them, from the question it looked like the `Label` was the problem irregardless of the content of the imports. Maybe add to the question where to get the files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although manifested as an MsBuild error this is really a problem with SpecFlow (check the full error, the line number points to TechTalk.SpecFlow.targets where it invokes the GenerateAll task which is imported from specflow.exe in TechTalk.SpecFlow.tasks): SpecFlow's NuGet package's dlls are built against .Net35 which does not support the `Label` attribute on `PropertyGroup`. So when you pass it a project file, like yours, which happens to contain such Label somewhere specflow fails.

SpecFlow claims to work with .Net40 so you can probably build the NuGet package against .Net40 from source yourself, then use it instead of the online version. Or raise a support ticket with SpecFlow: after all .Net35 is already quite old.

Comment: So MSBuild switches versions when it encounters a binary that's pre .Net4?

Comment: Not exactly. In fact msbuild itself doesn't have much to do with the error: it just displays it. The error itself is generated in the SpecFlow code parsing the project file, not in msbuild. Now that parsing code probably uses some classes from a .Net namespace like `Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine` which might very well also be used by msbuild, but that is the only link between the error and msbuild.